# Filtering values from coredata and assign to tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

The values of my coredata entity `Order` is stored in `orderDetails`. `orderDetails` has a count of 8 and it has columns like `orderId`, `remaining Balance` and `deliveryType`. The column `deliveryType` has values `Payment Pending`, `Delivery Pending` etc. There are 2 entries having `Payment Pending`. And I want to get these two entries and their values of `orderId` and `remaining Balance`.

In `viewWillAppear` I’m doing this…

```
for result in orderDetails {
     if let delType = result.value(forKey: "deliveryType") as? NSString {
             if delType == "Payment Pending" {

              }
          }
      }
```

This just takes me to that entry having value “`Payment Pending`”. But how do I proceed further.. I mean how can I give the count in `numberOfRowsInSection` and assign the proper values in `cellForRowAt`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of your for loop, use this code :-

```
let paymentPendingData = orderDetails.filter{ ($0.deliveryType ?? "").lowercased() == "payment pending" }
```

This will filter the payment pending data from your orderDetails and store to the array paymentPendingData which again is an array of type Order. You can use the count of that array.

Comment: Thanks @Vincent Joy. Worked fine! Have given an upvote too...:)

Comment: .@Vincent Joy just a doubt...do we need to always mention as .lowercased or can we just give something like `let paymentPendingData = orderDetails.filter{ ($0.deliveryType ?? "") == "Payment Pending" }`

Comment: I added it for some extra security. If you are getting that data from server and some programmer forgot to add it exactly in that word case format, this logic won't work.

Comment: oh..ok...Thanks...else it'll work without that also right...?

Comment: Yeah it will work. Or else, instead of "==" type, you can use contains() method also. Then it will check irrespective of what format that word is. ie, orderDetails.filter{ ($0.deliveryType ?? "").contains("Payment Pending") }

Comment: Ok @Vincent Joy Thanks a lot again...:)